# Primeng table filter not working on column with nested object

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a primeng table where on column value is obtained from a nested object.I am unable to filter the table using that column value.The filter works fine if enter value present in other columns.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Here is my typescript:

```
this.cols = [
      { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
      { field: 'email', header: 'Email' },
      { field: 'phnNumber', header: 'Contact No' },
      { field: 'grades[0].grade1', header: 'Grade' },

    ];
```

here is my filter:

```
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <p-table [columns]="cols" #dt [value]="students" [autoLayout]="true" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10">
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
            <div style="text-align: right">
                <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
                <input type="text" pInputText size="30" placeholder="Search" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" class="filter">
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-header" *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                    {{col.header}}
                    <p-sortIcon class="" [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order">
                    </p-sortIcon>
                </th>

            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-student let-columns="columns">
            <tr class="center-text">
                <td class="row-cell">{{student.name}}</td>
                <td class="row-cell">
                    {{student.email}}
                </td>

                <td class="row-cell">{{student.grades[0].grade1}}</td>

            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>

</div>
```

If I enter any value present in the grade column,I get empty response.
I think there's some issue with using grades[0].grade1 as field.

JSON Structure:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "email": null,
        "phnNumber": 1,
        "grades": [
            {
                "grade1": "A",
                "grade2": "B"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Stackblitz- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbwfep

Comment: Which column filter is not working ? can you add full html code to understand your question?

Comment: @CodeChanger please see now.

Comment: can you share student structure, here name seems like string and next moment you are using as an array?

<td class="row-cell">{{student.name}}</td>

And 

<td class="row-cell">{{student.name[0].grade}}</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use name[0].grade as filed property in column configuration. It can be any nested object. Filter is working.

The fact is that data on the table should the same property.

**Update:** You have to implement custom sorting and filter method of the table. Sorting is dynamic, as we know on which filed user want to sort based on click event, identifying the key is easy. But in the filter we don't know, the filter works for all the fields, so I have taken the 'grade1' field as of now to filter, you can add as many as field and remove after the filter.

I guess in case of a nested object, it doesn't work default, so you have to add custom implementation. Hope this helps.

component.html

```
<hello name="{{ title }}"></hello>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p-table [columns]="cols" #dt [value]="students" [autoLayout]="true" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" (onSort)="onSort($event)">
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
            <div style="text-align: right">
                <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
                <input type="text" pInputText size="30" placeholder="Search" (input)="myFilter($event)" class="filter">
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-header" *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                    {{col.header}}
                    <p-sortIcon class="" [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order">
                    </p-sortIcon>
                </th>

            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-student let-columns="columns">
            <tr class="center-text">
                <td class="row-cell">{{student.name}}</td>
                <td class="row-cell">
                    {{student.email}}
                </td>
                <td class="row-cell">
                    {{student.phnNumber}}
                </td>
                <td class="row-cell">{{student.grades[0].grade1}}</td>

            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>

</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { Component,
         ViewChild,
         AfterViewInit,
         ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "Filter in Table";
  cols = [];
  grades = [{ grade1: "grade1", grade2: "grade2" }];
  students = [];
  @ViewChild('dt',{read: '',static:true}) dt: any;

  constructor() {
    this.cols = [
      { field: "name", header: "Name" },
      { field: "email", header: "Email" },
      { field: "phnNumber", header: "Contact No" },
      { field: this.grades[0]["grade1"], header: "Grade1" }
    ];
    this.students = [
      {
        name: "Abhinav",
        email: "abhinavkumar985@gmail.com",
        phnNumber: "23456787654",
        grades: [
          {
            grade1: "AA",
            grade2: "X"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Ravi",
        email: "Ravi@gmail.com",
        phnNumber: "1234543666",
        grades: [
          {
            grade1: "CC",
            grade2: "Y"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Harsh",
        email: "hardss@gmail.com",
        phnNumber: "23212324",
        grades: [
          {
            grade1: "BB",
            grade2: "Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
  myFilter(e){
    this.dt.value.forEach((e)=>{
      e['grade1'] = e['grades'][0]['grade1'];
    });
    this.dt.filterGlobal(e.target.value, 'contains');
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.dt.value.forEach((e)=>{
      delete e['grade1'];
    });
    },500)
  }
  onSort(e){
    let filed = e.field;
    let arr = [...this.students];
    if(filed === 'grade1'){
      // custome sort only for these fields

      let order = e.order; // 1 means abc and -1 means cba
      if(order === 1){
        this.students.sort( this.OrderListBy(filed) );
      }else{
        this.students.sort( this.OrderListBy(filed) ).reverse();
      }
    }
  }
  OrderListBy(prop) {
    return function (a, b) {
        if (a['grades'][0][prop] > b['grades'][0][prop]) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (a['grades'][0][prop] < b['grades'][0][prop]) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

[see updated working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpwy5b)

Comment: My json structure is a bit different.In my case grade is itself an array of objects. Something like- grade:[ {grade1:'A',grade2:'B'}]

Comment: It would be easy if you share the whole structure and code on stackblitz

Comment: I've added the json structure to my question.please see

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Comment: bro can you please help me with this. I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: updated my answer, it was a bit tricky, you have to implement a custom filter and sort method of the table and have to add few dynamic properties and later remove them. Check details in answer. @rock11

Comment: I tried your code.It's working but the behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes I'm getting an empty response.

Comment: That was just a approach to solve this problem. I would recommend you to parse the json in plane object format before assigning to table. With that json structure you may have to override few of table functionality like searching , sorting etc. That will lead to unnecessary issue and cause performance issue. Better convert your data { name : '' , grade1: '', grade2:'' , grade3: ''} in this format. Will be easy and plain implementation.

Comment: I'll convert the data into a flattened format on client side.I think that'll be a good way to solve his issue.Thanks a lot man for your help.